# Algebra rearrangement, solve for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this equation for x?

$$1.43 = \frac{x}{0.99x+5.21\times10^{-5}}$$

I have tried rearranging it, but can't seem to get a positive number.

Comment: True! the solution is negative.

Comment: Are you *subtracting* $5$ in the denominator or not? Also, does the problem assert that $x$ is positive, because it could be negative as well. Anyway, as a hint, try getting $x$ onto one side of the equation, and then try to keep it on that side, but *alone*. In other words, try making $x$ the *subject* because it is our unknown value we want to solve for.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A = 1.43, B=0.99, C = 5.21 \times 10^{-5}$

The equation is $A = \frac{x}{Bx + C}$

Rearranging,

$ABx + AC = x$

$x(AB-1) = -AC$

$x = \frac{AC}{1-AB}$

which evaluates to approximately $x = -1.792 \times 10^{-4}$, indeed a negative real number.